# ggplot2 plot 3 factors with some x-axis jigging

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a points plot with ggplot2 geom_point where a continuous variable is stratified by different factors.

It is quite complicated, perhaps I am trying to show too much in one graph, but I have three different factors that influence things

I want to show it like this

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars[,c(1,2,10,11)], aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(gear), shape=factor(carb)))
```

[image]

However I want to split the factor(gear) out, i.e. for each of the three factor(cyl) value on the x axis, I want a small distance between the different factor(gear) colours on the x axis

i.e. within factor(cyl) == 4, factor(gear) == 3 is sort of on 3.9, factor(gear) == 4 is on 4 and factor(gear) == 5 is sort of on 4.1. This repeated for each factor(cyl) value.

Hope that makes sense

NB this is a toy example. I would be doing it using categorical, non-numeric values instead of factorised numbers; I realise having values on 3.9/4.1 is confusing.

Comment: why not facet the data on gear to give three plots?

Comment: facet sounds good, I am trying to figure it out using this: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html

Comment: if found this link quite useful for ggplot2 - http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `facet_grid()` and mtcars example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(carb)))
p + facet_grid(. ~ gear)
```

[image: By number of gears]

Comment: This is great. Is there a simple way to change the properties of the text at the top of the different facets (perhaps this should be a separate question!)

Comment: Scrap that, there is a great example here: http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Facets%20%28ggplot2%29/ (thanks a lot for the link John!)

Answer (score 4):

`subset` is one way to do this. Subset the data by `gears`, then position the set of points for each subset in turn.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot()
p + geom_point(data = subset(mtcars[,c(1,2,10,11)], gear == 3), aes(x = as.numeric(factor(cyl)) - 0.1, y = mpg, colour = factor(gear), shape=factor(carb))) +
    geom_point(data = subset(mtcars[,c(1,2,10,11)], gear == 4), aes(x = as.numeric(factor(cyl)), y = mpg, colour = factor(gear), shape=factor(carb))) +
    geom_point(data = subset(mtcars[,c(1,2,10,11)], gear == 5), aes(x = as.numeric(factor(cyl)) + .1, y = mpg, colour = factor(gear), shape=factor(carb))) +
   scale_x_continuous("Cylinders", breaks = c(1,2,3), labels = c(4,6,8), expand = c(.2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This works with the example I gave, but would it work when using a categorical value instead of numeric for Cylinders?

Comment: Don't see why not. You can try it on the mtcars data after some recoding: `library(car); mtcars$cyl = factor(recode(mtcars$cyl, "4 = 'Four'; 6 = 'Six'; 8 = 'Eight'"), levels = c("Four", "Six", "Eight"))`   I always prefer facetting, but the solution does actually do exactly what you asked for.